# Mendeley - References in Bibliography that I did not insert (MS Word 2016 plugin)

Tags: reference-managers

I have references in my bibliography (that Mendeley automatically generates for me) that are not in my paper. How do I get rid of them? MS Word 2016, Mendeley Plugin, Windows 10.

I have tried:

- Clicking the `Refresh` button
- Deleting the bibliography and re-inserting it

Answer (score 1):

I (kind of) solved the problem. I removed citations in earlier versions of the document and for some reason they were still being inserted into the bibliography. All cases were cases in which a there were multiple parenthetical citations. I deleted the entire set of citations and re-inserted them, and it's working again.

Comment: So, unlike the question title, you had originally inserted them, ie Mendeley was not just putting them in by magic...

Comment: Yes and no. They were once in there, but deleted long ago and did not show up in any parenthetical citations.